# Ajax Toolkit in Control Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, controls, toolkit

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#TextBox1").click(function() { alert("bla bla bla bla bla") });
        });

    </script>

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TabContainer runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Easd">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="asdasd">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    asd</ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>
```

i need TextBox1 access

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I need access", but I'm assuming you mean your jQuery code isn't working.

The generated clientside ID for serverside controls is different than your designed markup. You need to update your jQuery code:

```
$("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").click(function() { alert("bla bla bla bla bla"); });
```

This will dynamically insert the Client ID for the textbox, such that your jQuery selector will work.

**Edit:**

If you need value as you commented:

```
$("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").click(function() { alert( $(this).val() ); });
```

I'm only calling the javascript function `alert`and jquery event `click` based on your example code. As another example, if you wanted to alert/popup the value of the textbox when the user focuses away from it:

```
$("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").blur(function() { alert( $(this).val() ); });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Not Work "KP"

$("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").click(function() { alert( $(this).val() ); });

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          alert($("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").val());
        }); 
</script>
```

[Link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/5758.aspx)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
            alert($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val());
        }); 

<asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Entry Quato">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="ASD" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>

Error: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). Please Help me :(

Comment: yes script block

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val());
        }); 
    
    </script>

Comment: Instead of <%= in the script block, try <%#.  I updated my code above and provided a link to an article about it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
          alert($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val());
        }); 
</script>
Dont Work Jon help me :(

Comment: Try to use <%# instead of <%=, I updated the code above and provided a link to an article with someone having the same issue.

Comment: Dont work Jon :S :(

$(document).ready(function() {
            alert("asd");
            alert($("#<%#TextBox1.ClientID %>").val());
        }); 

        <asp:TabContainer runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Easd">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>

Comment: Does it produce the same error: Error: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)?

Comment: Sorry :-( I think I'm out of ideas, I wish I could be more of a help!  I'll keep thinking though